# Default select option for EntityType Field

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

I have two classes `User.php` and `Group.php`, extended from the classes defined in **fosuserbundle** .

Besides this I have a `ManyToMany` relation between them .

The idea of the application is when I add a new user, I assign one or many groups to user (I am using material design multi select option). The problem arises when user does not have any group(s) assigned (e.g when group option is empty). I get this javascript error in the console:

> An invalid form control with name='user[groups][]' is not focusable.

So to resolve this issue, I need to provide a default value for group field. How to set a default user group if group is not selected ? My classes are defined as follow.

> UserType.php

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'username',
                null,
                array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'username'
                ),
            ))
            ->add(
                'email',
                null,
                array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'email'
                ),
            ))
            /*->add('groups', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Group',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false
            ))  */
            ->add('groups', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Group',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'attr'=>array(
                    'class' => 'mdb-select'
                ),
                'multiple' => true,
            )) 
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'invalid_message' => 'Les mots de passe doivent être identiques.',
                'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Mot de passe'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Répétez le mot de passe'),
            ))
            //<input id="input-id"  type="file" class="file" multiple data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="true">
            ->add('enabled', null, array(
                'required' => false, 
            ))
            ->add('imageFile',VichFileType::class, [
                'required' => false,   
                'download_link' => true,
                'attr'=>array(
                'type' => 'file',
                'onchange' => 'loadFile(event)'), // not mandatory, default is true
            ])
        ;
    }
```

> GroupEntity.php

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('roles', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'   => ChoiceType::class,
                'entry_options'  => array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class'=>'mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-default'
                    ),
                    'choices'  => array(
                        'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                        'USER'     => 'ROLE_USER',
                    ),
                )
            ))
        ;
    }
```

> User.php

```
 <?php


    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
    use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

    /**
     * @Vich\Uploadable
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields="usernameCanonical", errorPath="username", message="fos_user.username.already_used", groups={"Default", "Registration", "Profile"})
     * @UniqueEntity(fields="emailCanonical", errorPath="email", message="fos_user.email.already_used", groups={"Default", "Registration", "Profile"})
     */
    class User extends BaseUser {

        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * 
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * 
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Group", inversedBy="users", cascade={"remove"})
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         * )
         */
        protected $groups;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=6, options={"default":0})
         */
        protected $loginCount = 0;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        protected $firstLogin;
        /**
         * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
         * 
         * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="user_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
         * 
         * @var File
         */
        private $imageFile;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
         *
         * @var string
         */
        private $imageName;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",nullable=true)
         *
         * @var \DateTime
         */
        private $updatedAt;


        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->enabled = true;
            $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
        }
    }
```

> Group.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group as BaseGroup;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_group")
 */
class Group extends BaseGroup
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;

    /** 
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="groups") 
      * 
      *   
      */ 
     protected $users;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $roles;

    /**
     * Group constructor.
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param array  $roles
     */
    public function __construct($name, $roles = array())
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the default data when creating the form. For example in your controller you'll have:

```
$user = new User();
// Add default groups to the $user
// ...
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $data = $form->getData();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ,  so i need the setGroups function in my user class :
setGroups(Collection $groups = null) {
        if ($groups !== null)
            $this->groups = $groups;}
Then , as u say :   $user->setGroups($something)); ??

Comment: @safe Yes, this should be what you want. The `$user` is the default value for the form which is just updated when you call `$form->submit()`. So if the submitted data don't contain any groups than it'll stay with the default value.

Comment: how i can initialise a Collection ?
I need to change $something and set a deffault collection object .

Comment: If you mean `ArrayCollection` from Doctrine2 then it behaves just like any other array and it has also some special methods. See http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate your help .

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by adding a 'POST_SET_DATA' or 'PRE_SUBMIT' form event to assign a group to the user if there aren't any groups in the form data.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POS_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();


        if (!$user->getGroups->count() > 0) {
            //...
        }
    });
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html

you could also use a lifecycle callback for your user entity

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html

or directly modify the object in your controller (@martin 's answer)

Comment: Thank your for u'r reponse , i want t say that i have a javascript error in my console : 

new:1 An invalid form control with name='user[groups][]' is not focusable.

Comment: Weird try and look in the concerned script if you manage to find where the error comes from.shouldn't be related to your form listener.You should probably ask another question for that. Please consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer if you found it helpful so others may benefit from it.

Comment: Done ,and thank your replying i really appreciate your help .